# When I call a function inside another function, the return value doesn't get printed out, so I need to use the print function

Tags: python-3.x, function, behaviorsubject

I created this two functions computepay() and calculateOverTime. I called calculateOverTime in computepay, did the math and returned it. I expected the result math from calculateOverTime to get printed out by print(computepay(floatHours, floatRate). What am I doing wrong?

```
def calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate):
    overtimeHours = floatHours - 40
    regularPay = (floatHours-overtimeHours)*floatRate
    overtimeRate = floatRate * 1.5
    overtimePay = overtimeHours*overtimeRate
    overtimePayment = overtimePay+regularPay
    return overtimePayment

def computepay(floatHours, floatRate):
if floatRate<=40:
    if floatHours>40:
        calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate)
    else:
            regularPay = floatHours*floatRate
            return regularPay
    else:
        print("I can't process this shit")

try:
    floatHours = input("Enter the hours:")
    floatHours = float(floatHours)
    floatRate = input("Enter the rate:")
    floatRate = float(floatRate)

except:
    print("Wrong Inputs")
    input("Try again")

print(computepay(floatHours, floatRate))

input("Close please")
```

Comment: Only one branch in ``computepay`` actually returns something.

Comment: Pls, familiarise yourself with PEP8 and provide in future formatted code it will be more readable and protect users' eyes.

Comment: Sorry, but thanks for the callout. Just started three days ago and got a little bit too excited this morning and wrote this with absolutely no regard to readability. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries. You can just [edit] your question to fix the indentation and other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed return when calling the calculateOverTime method.

```
return calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate)
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know you had to return the value of the function. Thought that the function automatically had the value inside of her. Thank you for the information. Really apreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
def computepay(floatHours, floatRate):
    if floatRate<=40:
        if floatHours > 40:
            amount=calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate)
            return amount

        else:
            regularPay = floatHours * floatRate
            return regularPay
    else:
        print("I can't process this shit")
```

You are missing to return calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate) which I took in the variable amount and then return it. You can directly use  return calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate) as well

Comment: An answer should have any description or explanation. Do not duplicate answers.

Comment: Actually I am new here and when I tried first it showed me some formatting error here which I later fixed with ctrl+k. However, I have fixed the code on my platform and later I have pasted it here. But I will make sure in future to reply to the point only rather than giving the program.

Answer (score -1):

I checked your code and got it working.

You're missing to return the `calculateOverTime` function in your `compute_pay` function, therefore instead of just calling the function, add a return at the beginning:

`return calculateOverTime(floatHours, floatRate)`